# Android Emulator abruptly crashes with a message "Saving state..."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I run the emulator of the android studio, the emulator abruptly crashes.

Many people face problems that there emulator doesn't work at all. But in my case, when I run the `Pixel API 30` virtual device, it works fine but when running on `Nexus-6` virtual device, the emulator simply crashes. I wanted to have a look that how my app looks when running on a tablet. But as soon as the boot is completed, there is a message saying "Saving state..." and then the emulator crashes.

I searched many places but didn't get a satisfactory answer.

It appears like this...

[image]

If someone familiar with this problem helps me then I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. It worked for me. While creating the android emulator, keeping boot option as `Cold boot` instead of `Quick boot` helps a lot. Boot option is in the Advanced Settings while creating emulator.